# Deleting after doing a search gives a dummy row

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a list of entries in a view. The view also has a searchbar on top. When a search is made, the search results are shown properly. Now after the search results are shown, I delete one of the entry. This also works fine. But when I start deleting the search characters entered in the search field a dummy field (which was related to the deleted entry) with just the delete and edit icons is shown like so...

[image]

Here the deleted records are still displayed as empty while they should not have been displayed at all.

This is the code I have written in searchbar `textDidChange`...

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText != "" {
            charInSearchBar = true

            //filter the results
            searchActive = true

            filtered = self.allCategories.filter({( data : CategoryItems) -> Bool in

                if let sdf = data.category {
                     return (sdf.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
                }

               return false
            })

            if(filtered.count == 0){
                noSearchChar1 = true 
                noSearchChar = true

            } else {
                searchActive = true
            }
            tableview.reloadData()
        } 

else {  

            noSearchChar1 = false
            searchActive = false
            self.tableview.reloadData()

        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

This is how the deleting of a row is done...

```
    func deleteTapped(cell: ProductCategoryTableViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableview?.indexPath(for: cell) {

            if (searchActive) {

                deleteBtnTapped = true
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Delete this Category?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)


                let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
                    context.delete(self.filtered[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
                    self.filtered.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    // try context.save()
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                        print("saved!")
                    } catch let error as NSError  {
                        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }

                    self.tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                     self.deleteBtnTapped = false


                }
       }
}
```

Comment: show how do you delete a row

Comment: .@Milan Nosáľ The code to delete a row has been added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the item not only from `filtered`, but from `self.allCategories` as well.

```
context.delete(self.filtered[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)

// here remove it from allCategories as well
if let indexInAllCategories = self.allCategories.index(of: self.filtered[indexPath.row]) {
    self.allCategories.remove(at: indexInAllCategories)
}

self.filtered.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```